# Couchbase "Bucket with given name still exists"

Tags: couchbase

I'm running Couchbase Version: 2.5.1 enterprise edition (build-1083-rel) 2 server  cluster on Windows

I created some test bucket to play with it. After some experiments I decide to "purge" it by delete|recreate.

Now I can't recreate bucket with same name - still getting  "Bucket with given name still exists". I discovered folder with bucket name still exists on secondary server in cluster (30 minutes after deletion). I tried to delete this folder manually without restarting Couchbase. Deletion was successfully but I still can't recreate bucket with same name (still get "Bucket with given name still exists").

How do I fix this?

Comment: Firstly, deleting the folder on the other node won't help you - as the cluster manager will still have that bucket configured.

I'm not sure why the bucket wasn't deleted in the first place though - is replication working correctly between these two nodes?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, I don't know the cluster has got into this situation, but you may be able to fix it by [rebalancing out the node](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/index.html#removing-a-node-from-a-cluster) which still has the 'old' bucket present (UI: Server Nodes -> Remove, Rebalance) and then rebalance it back in, assuming that your first node has enough disk space for all the Bucket data.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem (using 2.1.1 here though) - how do you know which node has the old bucket?